# list error in Django

Tags: python, django, list

I´m using Django and try to pass a list from the view to the template and I´m receiving this error 
`int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Taginfo'`
Follow the python view code. Thanks for helping.

```
def datasource(request, datasource_id = 1):
# if there is
if Datasource.objects.filter(idestacao_meteo=datasource_id).count()>0 :
    result = Datasource.objects.get(idestacao_meteo=datasource_id)
    #if there is tags on this datasource        
    if Tag.objects.filter(datasource_idestacao_meteo = datasource_id).count>0:
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(datasource_idestacao_meteo = datasource_id)
        tagInfo = {'' : 0} 
        for tag in tags:
            tagInfo[tag.idtag] = Taginfo.objects.get(idtaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1)
    else:
        tags = None         
    return render_to_response('Datasource/datasource.html',
        {'datasource' : result, 'tags' : tags}
    )
else:
    return render_to_response('Datasource/datasourceDoesNotExist.html',
        {'datasource_id' : datasource_id }
    )
```

Sorry guys, here its the model code of this class:

```
class Datasource(models.Model):
idestacao_meteo = models.IntegerField(db_column='idESTACAO_METEO', primary_key=True, editable=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
nome_estacao = models.CharField(db_column='NOME_ESTACAO', max_length=45, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
fabricante = models.CharField(db_column='FABRICANTE', max_length=45, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
modelo = models.CharField(db_column='MODELO', max_length=45, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
node_idnode = models.ForeignKey('Node', db_column='node_idNODE')  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'datasource'
```

and Tag

```
class Tag(models.Model):
idtag = models.IntegerField(db_column='idTAG', primary_key=True, editable=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
desvio = models.FloatField(db_column='DESVIO', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
tempo_max = models.IntegerField(db_column='TEMPO_MAX', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
conv_rate = models.IntegerField(db_column='CONV_RATE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
taginfo_idtaginfo1 = models.ForeignKey('Taginfo', db_column='tagInfo_idtagInfo1')  # Field name made lowercase.
datasource_idestacao_meteo = models.ForeignKey(Datasource, db_column='datasource_idESTACAO_METEO')  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'tag'
```

I check the names, they aren´t wrong. The problem is how I´m passing the list to the template.
And here it is the template:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2> Datasource ID: {{ datasource.idestacao_meteo }} </h2>
    <h2>Name: {{ datasource.nome_estacao }}</h2>
    <p>Manufacturer: {{ datasource.fabricante }}</p>
    <p>Model: {{ datasource.modelo }}</p>
    <hr size="4" width="100%"  noshade>
    {% if tags.count > 0 %}                     
        {% for tag in tags %}
            <div>
                <h3><a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tags/get/{{ tag.idtag }}/">Tag {{ tag.idtag }}</a></h3>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
</body>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: tag.idtag is of which type?? it is an int, a string or a tagInfo? and "tags" is not in the scope of "return render_to_response('Datasource/datasource.html',
        {'datasource' : result, 'tags' : tags}"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This question is marginal at best in meeting the guidlines for questions here [help] .   You are fortunate that generous answerers have taken the trouble to figure it out.   Nonethless, it will likely be closed if you don't fix it.   At the very least, you need to post the full traceback of the error.  Ideally, you should try to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (though that can be hard for django).  I'm pointing this out so you're aware for next time: this question is currently under review for closure, flagged as not meeting the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

`idtaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1`

Likely needs to be

`idtainfo_id = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1`